# Auto-sort html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      background: lightblue;
      padding: 32px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 45px;
    }


    p {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
  </style>

 
  <p>TABLE</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <table class="table table-striped" class="table table-sortable">
    <tr class="bg-info">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>CLUB</th>
      <th>PLAYED</th>
      <th>WINS</th>
      <th>LOSSES</th>
      <th>AT HOME</th>
      <th>AWAY</th>
      <th>POINTS SCORED</th>
      <th>POINTS ALLOWED</th>
      <th>POINT DIFFERENTAL</th>
      <th>POINTS</th>

    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    var timovi = [
      {
        at_home: "1-0",
        club: "Team1",
        losses: 0,
        away: "1-0",
        played: 2,
        wins: 2,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 98,
        point_difference: 82,
        points_allowed: 16
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-0",
        club: "Team2",
        losses: 0,
        away: "2-0",
        wins: 2,
        played: 2,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 90,
        point_difference: 66,
        points_allowed: 24
      },
      {
        at_home: "2-0",
        club: "Team3",
        losses: 0,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 2,
        played: 2,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 59,
        point_difference: 32,
        points_allowed: 27
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-1",
        club: "Team4",
        losses: 2,
        away: "1-1",
        wins: 1,
        played: 3,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 49,
        point_difference: -72,
        points_allowed: 121
      },
      {
        at_home: "1-0",
        club: "Team5",
        losses: 0,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 1,
        played: 1,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 62,
        point_difference: 10,
        points_allowed: 52
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-0",
        club: "Team6",
        losses: 0,
        away: "1-0",
        wins: 1,
        played: 1,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 20,
        point_difference: 4,
        points_allowed: 16
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-1",
        club: "Team7",
        losses: 2,
        away: "0-1",
        wins: 0,
        played: 2,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 44,
        point_difference: -13,
        points_allowed: 57
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-2",
        club: "Team8",
        losses: 2,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 0,
        played: 2,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 21,
        point_difference: -71,
        points_allowed: 92
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-0",
        club: "Team9",
        losses: 2,
        away: "0-2",
        wins: 0,
        played: 2,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 23,
        point_difference: -71,
        points_allowed: 94
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-1",
        club: "Team10",
        losses: 1,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 0,
        played: 1,
        points: 1,
        ppg: 16,
        point_difference: -4,
        points_allowed: 20
      }
    ]

    buildTable(timovi)



    function buildTable(data) {
      var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = `<tr>
              <td>${i+1}</td>
          <td>${data[i].club}</td>
          <td>${data[i].played}</td>
          <td>${data[i].wins}</td>
          <td>${data[i].losses}</td>
          <td>${data[i].at_home}</td>
          <td>${data[i].away}</td>
          <td>${data[i].ppg}</td>
          <td>${data[i].points_allowed}</td>
              <td>${data[i].point_difference}</td>
              <td>${data[i].points}</td>
                      </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row


      }
    }

  </script>

<style>
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code.

So I'm trying to make a website where you have basketball teams and see sorted table by points, if 2 or more teams have the same amount of points then it's by point_difference but not on a click when page loads. I'm spending hours on this please help.
[image]
I don't want to sort
[image]
I want to sort

```
    const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

    const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
      v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

    // do the work...
    document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener( 'click',(() => {
      const table = th.bodovi('table');
      Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));
    })));
```

I've tried this but that isn't what I want.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Sorting the data on page load or the actual sorting algorithm?

Comment: everything works but I don't know how to actually sort the table

Comment: Sorting *the table* seems like an unnecessarily obtuse approach.  Ideally you would sort *the data* and then simply generate the table from the data.

Comment: Ok, if that's easier but I don't know how to do that either. (I'm a begginer in html)

Comment: I'm confused. the code seems to do what you want: sort the data on page load.

Comment: If I change the value of somethig it stays where it was. (Second picture)

Comment: I see. that data is already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `timovi` has the builtin function `sort`. You can call it with a comparer function, to define what is bigger than what:

```js
function compareData(itemA, itemB)
{
  let pointDiff = itemB.points - itemA.points;
  if(pointDiff == 0)
  {
    pointDiff = itemB.point_difference - itemA.point_difference;
  }
      
  return pointDiff;
}
```

`sort` sorts in place, so the rest of your code can stay the same.

```js
var timovi = [
      {
        at_home: "1-0",
        club: "Team1",
        losses: 0,
        away: "1-0",
        played: 2,
        wins: 2,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 98,
        point_difference: 82,
        points_allowed: 16
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-0",
        club: "Team2",
        losses: 0,
        away: "2-0",
        wins: 2,
        played: 2,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 90,
        point_difference: 66,
        points_allowed: 24
      },
      {
        at_home: "2-0",
        club: "Team3",
        losses: 0,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 2,
        played: 2,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 59,
        point_difference: 32,
        points_allowed: 27
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-1",
        club: "Team4",
        losses: 2,
        away: "1-1",
        wins: 1,
        played: 3,
        points: 4,
        ppg: 49,
        point_difference: -72,
        points_allowed: 121
      },
      {
        at_home: "1-0",
        club: "Team5",
        losses: 0,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 1,
        played: 1,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 62,
        point_difference: 10,
        points_allowed: 52
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-0",
        club: "Team6",
        losses: 0,
        away: "1-0",
        wins: 1,
        played: 1,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 20,
        point_difference: 4,
        points_allowed: 16
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-1",
        club: "Team7",
        losses: 2,
        away: "0-1",
        wins: 0,
        played: 2,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 44,
        point_difference: -13,
        points_allowed: 57
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-2",
        club: "Team8",
        losses: 2,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 0,
        played: 2,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 21,
        point_difference: -71,
        points_allowed: 92
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-0",
        club: "Team9",
        losses: 2,
        away: "0-2",
        wins: 0,
        played: 2,
        points: 2,
        ppg: 23,
        point_difference: -71,
        points_allowed: 94
      },
      {
        at_home: "0-1",
        club: "Team10",
        losses: 1,
        away: "0-0",
        wins: 0,
        played: 1,
        points: 1,
        ppg: 16,
        point_difference: -4,
        points_allowed: 20
      }
    ];

function compareData(itemA, itemB)
{
  let pointDiff = itemB.points - itemA.points;
  if(pointDiff == 0)
  {
    pointDiff = itemB.point_difference - itemA.point_difference;
  }
  
  return pointDiff;
}

timovi.sort(compareData);

console.log(timovi);
```